# How to use order by clause on date column which is saved in string format in iOS?

Tags: ios, sqlite, date, datetime

I have a table in which there many columns and one column is used to save date value in 'dd mm yyyy HH:MM:SS' but I am creating this column with TEXT datatype

```
  "create table if not exists TABLENAME (ID INTEGER, NAME TEXT,TIMESTAMP TEXT,AMOUNT)";
```

Here `TIMESTAMP` is the column where I want save my date value. And then I have inserted value in my `TIMESTAMP` column

```
- (void)insert {
  NSString* dbPath = [DBManager getdbpath];
  if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString* insertSQL =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into TABLENAME (ID,NAME, TIMESTAMP , AMOUNT values('%@','%@','%@','%@')",id,Name,TimeStamp, amount];
    const char* insertStatement = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertStatement, -1, &statement, NULL) ==
        SQLITE_OK) {
      if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"Done inserting");

      } else {
        NSLog(@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        NSLog(@"Error while inserting data into database");
      }
    }
    //        sqlite3_reset(statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
  }
  sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

So when I try to fetch from TABLENAME applying **order by DESC** clause to `TIMESTAMP` column the values are not fetched in the correct order.

For e.g if there are two date values **'02 05 2014 13:02:30'** and **'15 04 2014 14:10:15'**. If an order by desc timestamp is applied to this values returned are

```
1>15 04 2014 14:10:15
2>02 05 2014 13:02:30
```

instead of

```
1>02 05 2014 13:02:30
2>15 04 2014 14:10:15.
```

Comment: Why are you storing the date in that format? Obviously, it makes it hard to get what you want.

Comment: @JesseRusak so which is the correct format to store date

Comment: @Rani See http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html for a list of suggested date formats. I agree with Jesse, that I always store them as numeric values, via `timeIntervalSince1970` (equivalent to SQLite's `unixepoch`). If you use one of the string formats, e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, you might want to adopt the convention of always formatting this string using GMT/UTC for your `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I'd advise against `stringWithFormat` to build your SQL (your SQL would fail if the `name` had an apostrophe in it, e.g. `Seamus O'Connor`). I'd suggest `sqlite3_bind_text` (or `sqlite3_mprintf`). If you need counsel here, let us know.

Comment: BTW, I notice that you are using quotation marks around `id` and `amount` (which are numeric values, presumably). Do not store numeric values as strings, or else they may not sort correctly (they'll sort alphabetically rather than numerically). If binding numeric values, use `sqlite3_bind_int` or `int64` or `double` or whatever). If building SQL manually (which I would discourage you from doing), do not put quotes around these numeric values. I mention this, because this issue applies with `timeIntervalSince1970`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your string format puts the day first, so it will be sorted (alphabetically) by day first. You should change how you're storing dates to something which is naturally ordered by temporal value.

As you can see on the [SQLite data types page](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) the normal mechanisms are to store it as an ISO8601 string, real or integer.

I would suggest an integer; you can use NSDate's `timeIntervalSince1970:` to get the correct value. These will then be correctly sorted.